# Creating several objects with relationships in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I'm new to rails.

I have a signup form, where the user can create a project, at the same time, as signing up.
The project should get created, and the new user is made "Admin" of the project.

I have the following models:

```
class Project < A::B
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, :through => :roles
  has_one :admin, :through => :roles, :conditions => "role.name = 'admin'"
  has_many :members, :through => :roles, :conditions => "role.name = 'member'"
end 


class User < A::B
  has_many :roles
  has_many :projects, :through => :roles
end

class Role < A::B
   belongs_to :projects
   belongs_to :users
end
```

I'm looking for away to create encapsulate the setup of the relationship in the model layer,  and make it easy to create forms, show errors etc in the view, for all objects in the relationship.

Hope I'm clear, newbie to rails . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look at the screencasts by Ryan Bates:

- [Part1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
- [Part2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

Answer (score 1):

First off, to make creating the forms easier, I would recommend using a gem like [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) or [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).
Secondly, to make the nested model forms easier, I would recommend using a gem like [cocoon](http://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), which works perfectly together with either formtastic or simple_form. Cocoon makes it easy to create dynamic nested model forms.

Hope this helps.